# 'Flask' object has no attribute 'post' error for login unit test

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, flask, flask-login

I am trying to test my log in functionality with Flask-Testing.  I'm following the [Flask docs on testing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/) as well. The `test_login()` function raises `AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'post'`.  Why am I getting this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lucas/PycharmProjects/FYP/Shares/tutorial/steps/test.py", line 57, in test_login_logout
rv = self.login('lucas', 'test') <br> <br>
  File "/home/lucas/PycharmProjects/FYP/Shares/tutorial/steps/test.py", line 47, in login
return self.app.post('/login', data=dict(
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'post'
```

```
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase
from flask import Flask
from Shares import db
import manage

class test(TestCase):

def create_app(self):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    return app

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite://"
TESTING = True

def setUp(self):
    manage.initdb()

def tearDown(self):
    db.session.remove()
    db.drop_all()

def test_adduser(self):
    user = User(username="test", email="test@test.com")
    user2 = User(username="lucas", email="lucas@test.com")

    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()

    assert user in db.session
    assert user2 not in db.session

def login(self, username, password):
    return self.app.post('/login', data=dict(
        username=username,
        password=password
    ), follow_redirects=True)

def logout(self):
    return self.app.get('/logout', follow_redirects=True)

def test_login(self):
    rv = self.login('lucas', 'test')
    assert 'You were logged in' in rv.data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [Flask-Testing](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/) magically sets up a special app client object on the TestCase instance named `self.client`. Change all `self.app` to `self.client` and it should fix that issue.

Eg:

```
def login(self, username, password):
    return self.app.post('/login', data=dict(
        username=username,
        password=password
    ), follow_redirects=True)
```

to:

```
def login(self, username, password):
        return self.client.post('/login', data=dict(
            username=username,
            password=password
        ), follow_redirects=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @jumbopap However I now have an assertion error :'(

The error <TestResponse streamed [404 NOT FOUND]>
is thrown by the line         rv = self.login('lucas', 'test')

My route has the following definition:

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():



Any ideas what might be wrong? :)

Comment: Your actual production application isn't being tested by this test suite. You're creating an entirely separate app in `create_app` that doesn't have the `/login` route. You'll need to import your production app from wherever it is stored and return it in the `create_app` method.

Answer (score 1):

While writing tests for my Flask app I came across a similar problem.

Only from debugging I saw that there was no "config" attribute instead I had to go `self.app.application.config`

Not sure why it's missing, I've usually always done `self.app.config` just like in the production code

```
import unittest

from factory import create_app


class ConfigTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        app = create_app('flask_test.cfg')
        app.testing = True
        self.app = app.test_client()

    def test_app_is_development(self):
        self.assertFalse(self.app.application.config['SECRET_KEY'] is 'secret_key')
        self.assertTrue(self.app.application.config['DEBUG'] is True)
```